# How to have button overlap another button and slowly disappear

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to overlap two buttons. One button is a segmented control which slowly vanishes under the first button.
I'm wonder what's the best way to get this to display? Would I make it so the first button has no constraints and then add some transparency view underneath that would cause the segmented control / button to slowly disappear

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to do a "fade out from left" effect? Like the the segmented control fades out from left to right

Comment: This is a scrollable unit, so as you scroll to the right (swiping left), the segmented unit disappears underneath the button